# Effect on a rate

Tags: effect-size

I've got one independent variable and two dependent variables. As a concrete example, consider the independent variable to be *browser* (categorical, what Web browser a visitor to a Web site uses) and the dependent variables to be *visitors* (number of visitors) and *enrollers* (number of visitors who sign up for a newsletter). Note that *enrollers* depends on *visitors* (because every enroller is also a visitor).

I care about the [rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_%28mathematics%29) *enrollers/visitors* only. How can I determine the effect size of *browser* on the rate *enrollers/visitors*?

My specific concern is that I don't know to study *enrollers/visitors* where power and presumably effect size depend (also) on *visitors* itself.

Comment: There are many ways I believe. I would use logistic regression, but seems like poisson / neg bin regression with an offset for visitors could be used. Here are some other methods: http://statcompute.wordpress.com/. Sorry not much time to elaborate, but all are easy with R.

Comment: @msh210 are you still interested in the answer to this question?

Comment: @ConjugatePrior yes.

Comment: @msh210 is there something wrong with the one I provided?

Comment: @ConjugatePrior I didn't get notification of it when you posted it, so didn't see it until you posted the above comment, and haven't had a chance to check it thoroughly as of yet.

Comment: Ahhh.  Right.  I was beginning to wonder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A first cut logistic regression would be

```
model <- glm(cbind(enrolled, visitors-enrolled) ~ browser, family=binomial)
```

where browser is a dummy variable, (a `factor` in R), and `enrollers` and `visitors` are counts within some set of time periods.  Use `predict` to get predicted probability of a particular browser user enrolling once they have visited.

This model treats `enrolled` as a binomially distributed count with trial length `visitors` with shifts in enrollment probability due to browser choice (only). Since this is probably not quite true you might think of other things to put on the right hand side.

Here's a worked example with two browser types 'IE' and 'FF'

```
## Assume: IE has .3 chance of enrolling, FF has .6 chance of enrolling,
##         3/4 of browsers are IE,
##         visits in each of 200 time periods are Poisson distributed.

N <- rpois(200, 15) + 1;      ## visitors per time period, guaranteed positive
fake <- data.frame(enrolled=c(rbinom(rep(1,150), N[1:150], rep(.3,150)),
                              rbinom(rep(1,50), N[151:200], rep(.6,50))), 
                   visitors=N, 
                   browser=c(rep("IE", 150), rep("FF", 50)))

## fit model to fake data
model <- glm(cbind(enrolled, visitors-enrolled) ~ browser, family=binomial, data=fake)

## predict rate of enrollment for each browser type (should recover ~0.3 and ~0.6)
predict(model, newdata=data.frame(browser=c('IE', 'FF')), type='response')
```

The *difference* between these two probabilities is one possible measure of the effect of switching browsers.  Alternatively you could compute it in proportional increase in probability going from IE to FF with a division...

If the rate of enrollment is very small relative to visits you might be better doing

```
model <- glm(enrolled ~ browser + offset(log(visitors)), family=poisson, data=fake)
```

or some over-dispersed variant.  Here the probabilities are gotten by exponentiating the constant term (for FF) and then the constant term plus the coefficient for IE.  That should also get you about 0.6 and 0.3

We can be a bit more statistical about the effect size by generating a probability distribution for it.  Here's a sampling-based approach for the Poisson model above.  (We can often do the math in closed form, but who cares when we can always sample...)

```
## get the distribution of differences in enrollment rates for, say 20 visits

## simulate from the sampling distribution of the parameters
library(MASS) 
sim.param <- mvrnorm(n=500, mu=coef(model), Sigma=vcov(model))

## make a function to compute effect size
eff <- function(x){ exp(x[1] + log(20)) - exp(x[1]+x[2] + log(20)) }
## note: the log(20) above is doing the same thing as the offset above.

## apply it 500 times and summarize the results
diffs <- apply(sim.param, 1, eff)
plot(density(diffs))             ## the distribution of effect sizes
quantile(diffs, c(0.025, .975))  ## a 95% interval
```

The latter should be between 4.7 and 7 for 20 visits.  For other definitions of effect size, you'd just change the `eff` function to compute them and rerun.

Comment: Thank you! I'm probably missing something, but don't see how I would get effect size from this.

Comment: @msh210 I've put a bit more in about possible definitions and computations of effect size.  While you can also look these up in a book, I think it's helpful to sample instead because this method will generalize.  Also, the R code should run when pasted in now.